# Error during the installation of Cython

Tags: cython, simplecv

I have installed SimpleCV 1.3 powerpack in my Windows 8.1. Then i set up the required path. And then i installed pyreadline, PIL, pip, ipython via cmd. But when i tried to run easy_install cython, i'm getting the following error,

```
C:\Users\Ankit>easy_install Cython
Searching for Cython
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/Cython/
Best match: Cython 0.22
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/C/Cython/Cython-0.22.tar.gz#
md5=1ae25add4ef7b63ee9b4af697300d6b6
Processing Cython-0.22.tar.gz
Running Cython-0.22\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\ankit\appdata\local
\temp\easy_install-lvjvzj\Cython-0.22\egg-dist-tmp-aeuxtq
Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.
Compiling module Cython.Plex.Scanners ...
Compiling module Cython.Plex.Actions ...
Compiling module Cython.Compiler.Lexicon ...
Compiling module Cython.Compiler.Scanning ...
Compiling module Cython.Compiler.Parsing ...
Compiling module Cython.Compiler.Visitor ...
Compiling module Cython.Compiler.FlowControl ...
Compiling module Cython.Compiler.Code ...
Compiling module Cython.Tempita._tempita ...
warning: no files found matching '*.pyx' under directory  'Cython\Debugger\Test'

warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory   'Cython\Debugger\Test

warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython\Utility'
Scanners.c
C:\Python27\include\pyconfig.h(227) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include   file: 'basetsd.h': No such fil
e or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsof
t Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a double partition system Windows8/Xubuntu14.04LTS.
I had the same issue when attempting to `install Cython onto Xubuntu via pip`.

So I installed Cython with below command and and everything went ok.

`bashsh $ sudo apt-get install cython`

This is not the best fix. But, may worth a trial if you are really
looking to port an almost complete project to Windows8.

You compile your Python main (without main):

`bash $ cython --embed -o prog.c prog.py`

You may decide to `install Mxe (MingW) gcc on linux` and do 
cross compiling or, as me, to compile directly in the windows8:

`bash $ gcc -Os -IC:\Python27\include -LC:\Python27\libs -o prog.exe prog.c -lpython27 -DMS_WIN64`

Hope this might be of any help.