# Cython setup error : Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar

Tags: python, cython

In order to install cython ( for python 2.7 , windows 8.1 ), made the download in .zip format, extracted the whole file and run the setup.py . Thus, python shell shows this :
Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.

What is the problem and how it can be solved ?

Comment: Please see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29433941/error-during-the-installation-of-cython/32317660#32317660) helps which looks similar to you.

Comment: It should be possible to install and use Cython regardless of that message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant code in *setup.py* first tries to find *pgen*

```
 pgen = find_executable(
        'pgen', os.pathsep.join([os.environ['PATH'], os.path.join(get_python_inc(), '..', 'Parser')]))
    if not pgen:
        print ("Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.")
```

If *pgen* is found, then file `Cython/Parser/Grammar` is given as argument to *pgen*

```
    else:
        parser_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Cython', 'Parser')
        grammar = os.path.join(parser_dir, 'Grammar')
        subprocess.check_call([
            pgen,
            os.path.join(grammar),
            os.path.join(parser_dir, 'graminit.h'),
            os.path.join(parser_dir, 'graminit.c'),
            ])
```

The first lines of *Cython/Parser/Grammar*,

```
# Grammar for Cython, based on the Grammar for Python 3

# Note: This grammar is not yet used by the Cython parser and is subject to change.
```

That comment seems to suggests that even if *pgen* is available, the code produced by it won't be used.

Answer (score 4):

Much Simpler,

Try installing Cython from pip.
Windows- Open Python folder, press shift+right click, select "open command promt here"

> pip install cython

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in ubuntu. I first tried

```
sudo easy_install cython
```

It failed

Then I did it manually in the following manner:

```
mkdir cython
cd cython
wget http://cython.org/release/Cython-0.24.zip
unzip Cython-0.24.zip
cd Cython-0.24
sudo python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 1):

If installing `Cython` on `Raspberry Pi` and you get the error

> unable to find pgen

I found that installing `pgen` manually then running the `Cython` install worked!

```
sudo pip3 install pgen
```

Answer (score 0):

Try folollowing command,

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-pip libev4 libev-dev
sudo apt-get install cython3
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the following install option solved the problem:

```
pip install Cython==0.29.1 --install-option="--no-cython-compile"
```